# C++ indentation after member initialization list

Tags: indentation, c++

When I add a member initialization list to my class constructor, Emacs indents the body like this:

```
Vector::Vector(int s) : elem{new double[s]}, sz{s}
   {

   }
```

I expect it to be indented the same as when there is no member initialization list:

```
Vector::Vector(int s)
{

}
```

How can I accomplish this? Should I file a bug?

Answer (score 1):

What indentation style do you have configured?

(see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC)

I have style = "bsd" and emacs doesn't do that.

Comment: I'm using the default (`gnu`). I tried `(setq c-default-style "bsd")` but it's still misbehaving. Emacs version is 24.5.

Comment: does it still indent like this when you start with emacs -Q ?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think this was an Emacs 24.5 issue in `cc-mode` that has been fixed in 25.1. Note that using initialization lists to initalize variables (curly-braces) is C++11 construct, only recently supported in Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

```
(setq c-default-style "linux")
```

You could tweak indentation of individaul `c-syntactic-context` by manipulating the variable `c-offsets-alist`. Read wiki and documentation. Usually that's enough.

More advanced method is reading the original Lisp code if Emacs itself has issue. Here is step by step guide http://blog.binchen.org/posts/ccjava-code-indentation-in-emacs.html

I strongly suggesting reading the article to understand why at first. Then insert below code into your ~/.emacs **if ad only if** changing `c-default-style` does NOT solve the issue:

```
(defun fix-c-indent-offset-according-to-syntax-context (key val)
  ;; remove the old element
  (setq c-offsets-alist (delq (assoc key c-offsets-alist) c-offsets-alist))
  ;; new value
  (add-to-list 'c-offsets-alist '(key . val)))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (derived-mode-p 'c-mode 'c++-mode 'java-mode)
              ;; indent
              (fix-c-indent-offset-according-to-syntax-context 'func-decl-cont 0))
            ))
```